# Why wouldn't lodash 'some' function work as expected?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash 2.4.1 in order to know if *there's at least one element within an array with `true` as its value*.

So I decided to use lodash `some` or `any` function.

This is what my code looks like:

```
if ( _.some([lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers(), lineup.reachesBudgetLimit()], true) ) {
  response.send(400, "La inclusión de este jugador no satisface las reglas del juego");
}
```

Which is *never* going inside the if block, even that first condition actually evaluates to true.

I got:

```
console.log(lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers());
console.log(lineup.reachesBudgetLimit());
```

Before the `if` block and I can actually see first statement evaluating to `true`.

What could it be failing?

**I use lodash 2.4.1 as it's included Sails js dependency.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:**

Actually, just using `_.some`[<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://lodash.com/docs#some) with no predicate defaults to identity:

```
_.some(bool_arr)
```

should work.

```js
console.log(_.some([true, true, false]));
console.log(_.some([false, false, false]));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

In addition to the other answers that suggest passing `Boolean` as the predicate. You can also use:

```
_.some(bool_arr, _.identity)
```

---

> `_.identity`[<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://lodash.com/docs#identity)
>
> This method returns the first argument provided to it.

Comment: Could you explain why passing Boolean would work and what does_.identity do?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a function:

```
function isTrue(v) {
  return v === true;
}

if ( _.some([lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers(), lineup.reachesBudgetLimit()], isTrue) ) {
  response.send(400, "La inclusión de este jugador no satisface las reglas del juego"); 
}
```

Lodash doc: https://lodash.com/docs#some

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant to pass `Boolean` as the predicate (2nd argument)

Comment: I don't want to know if they're boolean but if they're True

Comment: That is exactly what passing Boolean will get you

Comment: What about the "passing an evaluating function approach"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Boolean is a function. Boolean(truthy-value) evaluates to true, and Boolean(falsy-value) evaluates to false. `_.some` expects a predicate (function) that returns true or false

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a non-function value to `some`, lodash treats it as a property name and tries to find an object which contain a non-falsy property with the name given. In your example, you pass `true`, so it tries to access `item1[true]`, `item2[true]` etc. Since none of them exists, the result is false.

The solution is to omit the second argument altogether, in which case it defaults to `identity`, that is, to the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

`_.some` is checking that the collection you give it contains at least one instance of an object of the type you are giving it. Observe:

```
> _.some([true, false], true)
false

> _.some([true, undefined], Boolean)
true
```

You can instead pass a function like so:

```
> _.some([true, false], function(value) { return value === true; })
true

> _.some([undefined, false], function(value) { return value === true; })
false
```

However, I would suggest using `if (lineup.reachesBudgetLimit() || lineup.reachesMaxForeignPlayers())`.

Comment: They will be more than two methods so that's why I rather use_.some

Comment: @diegoaguilar Oh, in that case, it definitely makes sense to use a different approach like `_.some`.